# Редактировяние столбца в JTable несколькими способами

Tags: java, swing, jtable

такой вопрос по яве.
Необходимо редактировать столбец в JTable двумя способами: выбор из списка или ввод вручную.
Есть какой-то сбособ, как это зделать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Примерно, так:

```
    JComboBox<Object> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
    comboBox.setEditable(true); // разрешаем ввод вручную
    
    DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
    table.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(cellEditor); // устанавливаем редактор для нужного столбца
```

Можно еще глянуть код  [org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.ComboBoxCellEditor](https://github.com/ebourg/swingx/blob/master/swingx-autocomplete/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/ComboBoxCellEditor.java) из swingx

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.